# What does Json.Decode.{} mean? The dot curly braces part

Tags: module, reason, bucklescript, bs-json

I'm trying to learn ReasonML and following the example for bs-json we can decode raw json into a type like this:

```rust
type point = {
  x: float,
  y: float
};

module Decode = {
  let point = json =>
    Json.Decode.{
      x: json |> field("x", float),
      y: json |> field("y", float)
    };
}
```

I'm a bit confused as to what this `Json.Decode.{ ... }` is.  I understand we can open up a scope into a module using the `.()` dot parenthesis, but I haven't seen this dot curly braces before.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means pretty much the same thing, that `Json.Decode` is opened in the scope of `{}`, which defines a record, as usual. Essentially just a short-hand for `Json.Decode.({ .. })`.

*Edit: I just added a note to `bs-json`s README, just below [the example](https://github.com/glennsl/bs-json#example), to explain this syntax.*